# Cannot change workitem's parent through the azure devops api

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to programatically change a workitem's parent using the azure devops api but it's not working as expected.

I tried using [update link endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update_a_link) and also [remove link endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#remove_a_link) but none of them seem to be the correct one given that there is no way I can get a relation ID for the parent-child relationship to use in the request path.

Answer (score 0):

The "relation ID" to send in `path:` is just the index of the relation being changed or removed in the [`WorkItemRelation[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#workitem) on the [Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#workitem) being PATCHed.

Use the `$expand=Relations` argument in the query string of the GET operation for the work item whose parentage you want to change ([Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)).

`https://dev.azure.com/{YOUR_ORG}/{YOUR_PROJ}/_apis/wit/workitems/{Child_ID}?$expand=Relations&api-version=5.0-preview.2`

*note: I'm not exactly sure, but I think the {YOUR_PROJ} value can be omitted.*

With the resulting workitem object, get the index of the relation where the relation type is `Hierarchy-Reverse`, and use this as the leaf of the `"path": "/relations/{index}"` property sent in the PATCH body with `op: "remove"`.

#### Get response (abbreviated):

```json
        {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{YOUR_ORG}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Parent_ID}",
            "attributes": {
                "isLocked": false
            }
        }
```

#### Patch request (body):

```json
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/relations/0"
  }
]
```

The examples in the documentation tend to perform a test on the revision of the work item before executing the remove or add operation. This isn't necessary, but it's probably a good idea.